# Better way to refactor $scope operations like this in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

My coffeescript codes looks like this

```
.controller('SignInController',
    ($scope, CONFIG, restAuth, cookieAuth) ->
        $scope.signInData = {}
        $scope.res = {}
        # TODO: Refactor this to service

        $scope.processRegistration = ->
            console.log($scope.signInData)
            restAuth.post('signin', $scope.signInData)
            .then(((data) ->
                    if data.res >= 0
                        $scope.res.signInSuccess = true
                        $scope.res.msg = 'You finished login successfully.'
                        cookieAuth.setCookie(data)
                    else
                        $scope.res.signInSuccess = false
                        $scope.res.msg = 'Your login failed. (#{ data.description })'
                ),
                (->
                    $scope.res.signInSuccess = false
                    $scope.res.msg = 'Sorry, it seems that the server is not responding. Please try again later!')
            )


        return
)

.controller('SignUpController',
    ($scope, $http, CONFIG) ->
        $scope.signUpData = {}
        $scope.res = {}
        # TODO: Refactor this to service

        $scope.processRegistration = ->
            $http
            .post('#{ CONFIG.ROOT }/auth/signup', $scope.signUpData)
            .success (data) ->
                if data.res >= 0
                    $scope.res.signUpSuccess = true
                    $scope.res.msg = 'You finished registration successfully.'
                else
                    $scope.res.signUpSuccess = false
                    $scope.res.msg = 'Your registration failed. (#{ data.description })'
            .error(->
                $scope.res.signUpSuccess = false
                $scope.res.msg = 'Sorry, it seems that the server is not responding. Please try again later!'
            )

        return
)
```

As can be seen, there are many operations on `$scope`, which looks a little clumsy.. Does anyone have suggestions about how to refactor this?

Comment: Put them in services. If you're using the function in your html maybe all the scope functions will do is calling the service functions.

Answer (score 0):

I followed John Papa style guide, he recommends controllerAs syntax over classic controller with $scope. Below is what he states:

> Use the controllerAs syntax over the classic controller with $scope
>   syntax.
>
> The controllerAs syntax uses this inside controllers which gets bound
>   to $scope
>
> Why?: controllerAs is syntactic sugar over $scope. You can still bind
>   to the View and still access $scope methods.
>
> Why?: Helps avoid the temptation of using $scope methods inside a
>   controller when it may otherwise be better to avoid them or move them
>   to a factory. Consider using $scope in a factory, or if in a
>   controller just when needed. For example when publishing and
>   subscribing events using $emit, $broadcast, or $on consider moving
>   these uses to a factory and invoke from the controller.

You may find the complete guidelines here:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide